# How to use hover and add text over node in d3 force simulation

Tags: d3.js, svg

I am trying to make d3 force simulation where i am parsing data from csv file and i am trying use hover and showing text over node but i am unable to show it though i am able to parsing csv file.
Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.link {
stroke: #000;
}

.node {
stroke: #fff;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>

var width = 960,
height = 500;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height);

var force = d3.layout.force()
.size([width, height]);

d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, links) {
if (error) throw error;

var nodesByName = {};

// Create nodes for each unique source and target.
links.forEach(function(link) {
link.source = nodeByName(link.source);
link.target = nodeByName(link.target);
});

// Extract the array of nodes from the map by name.
var nodes = d3.values(nodesByName);

// Create the link lines.
var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
.data(links)
.enter().append("line")
  .attr("class", "link");
// Create the node circles.
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
.data(nodes)
.enter().append("circle")
.attr("class", "node")
.attr("r", 4.5)
.call(force.drag);        
// Start the force layout.
force
.nodes(nodes)
  .links(links)
  .on("tick", tick)
  .start();

function tick() {
link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
    .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
    .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
    .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
}

function nodeByName(name) {
return nodesByName[name] || (nodesByName[name] = {name: name});
}
});

</script>
```

[Here, Is my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssTH1.png)

 
Actually, I am new in d3 force simulation, any suggestion is highly appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this would work,

```
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
.data(nodes)
.enter().append("circle")
.attr("class", "node")
.attr("r", 4.5)
.on("mouseover", handleMouseOver)
.on("mouseout", handleMouseOut);
.call(force.drag);
```

and then call the functions as in the example here http://bl.ocks.org/WilliamQLiu/76ae20060e19bf42d774

Comment: Thank you so much. Hover does work but text over node is not showing. But when i am trying get the text over node using id function handleMouseOver(d, i) {  // Add interactivity
            // Use D3 to select element, change color and size
            d3.select(this).attr({
              fill: "orange",
              r: 5 * 2
            });
            svg.append("text").attr({})
            .text(function() {
              return d.id;  // Value of the text
            });
          } my csv file looks like this: id source target >>> 1 AL AN; 2 AK ER

Comment: I could try it if you'd provide a bit of the csv data

Comment: I have figured it out and solved it in different way but your link helps me to solve the hover problem. Thanks.